# Java Webservice method return showing as compile type error?

Tags: java, web-services

i have one java webservice method where at place of return it is showing as error `The method ok() is undefined for the type Response`  Here is my code as follows

```
@Path("/deleteMethod")
  @GET
  @Produces({"application/json"})
  public Response deleteServiceMethod(@QueryParam("allPatients") boolean allPatients, @QueryParam("PatientName") String PatientName, @QueryParam("PatientPlace") String PatientPlace)
    throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {     
      //my logic is present here

      return Response.ok().build();      
  }
```

Can anybody tell me what kind of error this is ,should i need to add any jar for this?

Comment: Check your Response class, from what package have you imported it? It should be : `javax.ws.rs.core.Response`

Comment: @ACV, already i have added that though it is showing same error

Comment: May i know why Vote down please?

Comment: What server are you using? If on glassfish, it must work. If on tomcat, you'll need to include the jar. Please provide the whole class code to see (including imports)

Comment: @ACV,i'm working with Tomcat and included the above jar.But still shows same error.

Comment: what's the jar name?

Comment: @ACV, this  javax.ws.rs.jar  i have used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`return Response.status(200).entity("your payload").build();`

Comment: ACV, when i added the above line it is giving error as : The method status(int) is undefined for the type Response

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved this error.`//Type 1: import javax.xml.ws.Response;
Type2: import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;` Previously i used the Type1 import and commenting Type 1 and i used Type2 it got solved. Thanks Every one who helped me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

add an import:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
```